# Join array in a objects in a object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object

I call api and have an object:

```
    const body = { 
    data:{ 
        book: 
        [ { "name": "math", "class": 8, "level": 2 },
          { "name": "math", "class": 10, "level": 2} 
        ]
     }
 }
```

Now I want to get an array

```
 [ { "name": "math", "class": 8, "level": 2 },
   { "name": "math", "class": 10, "level": 2} 
 ]
```

But I get `const books = body.data.book and console.log(books)` and I have an undefined book. You can help me?

Comment: first try `console.log(body)` if it is correct

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and ran it. works perfectly for me.

Comment: @cmgchess I'd suggest `console.log(JSON.stringify(body))` instead. Without `JSON.stringify` it will show the current version on inspection, not the version at logging time (which could be the error, who knows)